# Flutter - How to send form validation as parameter type 'RequiredValidator' is not a subtype of type '((String?) => String?)?'

Tags: flutter, validation

I'm using `form_field_validator` package that provides alot of easy and fast validation methods but I'm facing a weird problem. I'm trying to create a reusable `TextFormField` input that only accepts the validation and some strings but flutter refuses to let me do that with that type of validation although it works like a charm if I use it directly without passing it. Code:

```
Widget input(String name, String value, var validator) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: responsiveWidth(20), right: responsiveWidth(20)),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(name),
          SizedBox(
            height: responsiveHeight(10),
          ),
          Container(
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.9,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: validator,
              decoration: inputDecoration(context, value),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Main:

```
// Other code
input("Email", "email@gmail.com",
                    RequiredValidator(errorText: "Required")

              )
// Other code
```

But I'm getting this error:
`type 'RequiredValidator' is not a subtype of type '((String?) => String?)?'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Main:

```
input("Email", "email@gmail.com")
```

**Custom Widget As:**

```
final requiredValidator = EmailValidator(errorText: 'Error Text'); //Add this on top of input widget.
```

```
Widget input(String name, String value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: responsiveWidth(20), right: responsiveWidth(20)),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(name),
          SizedBox(
            height: responsiveHeight(10),
          ),
          Container(
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.9,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: requiredValidator,
              decoration: inputDecoration(context, value),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: Can you please share the minimal reproducible code? I want to see the error.

Comment: The code I provided can be minimal reproducible code. Please just create a stateful widget and add the function ```input``` anywhere outside the ```build``` function then call it inside the ```build``` and remove the decoration for the sake of simplicity. Sorry for not editing the post but I don't want the question to be so long. Thanks for replaying.